# What use is the copper foil between the primary and secondary windings of a transformer?

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism

I took apart a small transformer. It is of shell construction type. Beneath the primary windings, I found a strip of (floating) copper foil wrapped around the secondary windings. Of course there is mylar insulation between those three components.

Based on what I read here: [Magnetics Design 4 - Power Transformer Design](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ml/slup126/slup126.pdf), small transformers have the problem of limited space, taken up by insulation and voids between round wires. A copper foil increases the copper volume that can provide better magnetic coupling.

Am I right in my explanation? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's there to reduce the coupling of high-frequency noise from the AC line, switching regulator harmonics, or other 'unclean' energy into the secondary winding.  The shield won't *improve* the magnetic coupling but it won't hurt it either, and energy at higher frequencies that would have been transmitted via interwinding capacitance will be attenuated.

Part of a defense-in-depth EMI control strategy, basically.

Comment: Otherwise known as an electrostatic shield.

Comment: An "electrostatic shield" is effectively a grounded capacitor plate that prevents capacitive coupling between windings. Instead both are coupled to ground capacitively.